# Onde colocar esta lógica? Controller ou Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Minha aplicação tem a seguinte lógica:

- Dado um link recebido, a aplicação pega o atributo `<title>` da página e transforma este atributo na descrição do link e salva no banco.

Coloquei esta lógica no *callback* `before_save` no *Model* e esta funcionando perfeitamente.

Este tipo de lógica, devo colocar no *Controller* ou o local correto é mesmo no model?

Comment: Como esse link chegar pro modelo? Acho justo o set desse atributo num before_save. Desde que seja apenas setar o valor num atributo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa dividir esta ação em:

Buscar o link, fazer a transformação na descrição ( isso é função do controller )

Salvar no banco de dados (isso é função do model)

Via de regra a persistencia dos dados, salvar no banco de dados, é sempre função do model. A lógica da sua aplicação, dependendo do tipo pode ir na View (um filtro inicial na entrada de dados por exemplo) e/ou no Controller.

Comment: Controllers com lógica, outra do que lidar com requests (função primordial deles), é anti-pattern. http://codebetter.com/iancooper/2008/12/03/the-fat-controller/

Answer (score 12):

Segundo o padrão MVC, toda a lógica, principalmente relacionada a banco de dados, deve ser colocada no Model.

Considere o padrão MVC como um computador. O Model é a CPU, a View é seu monitor e o Controller são as portas / cabos.

Views não têm lógica, assim como seu monitor. Ele é burro, só exibe o que o controller (cabos / portas) manda pra ele.

Controllers contém o mínimo de lógica possível, assim como cabos e portas: Eles são só o que conecta as Views e os Models.

Os Models, assim como a CPU, é quem faz todo o trabalho pesado: é responsável por qualquer lógica leve ou pesada (a mais comum delas sendo a persistência). É ela quem trata tudo que o Controller manda pra ela; e o Controller manda assim como recebeu, quem vai receber, tratar, formatar e manipular será o Model.

Comment: Essa foi a melhor explicação do conceito MVC que eu vi até hoje...

Comment: Então Andre... Pense que tenho que montar uma agenda que é composta por eventos e locações. Quem é responsavel de fazer o merge dessas entidades e entregar pra view?  :)

Comment: @RafaelSoufraz Todo o trabalho de manipulação dos dados (provavelmente os SELECTs do SQL) são definidos como métodos no Modelo. O Controlador usará os métodos de cada model pra juntar tudo e mandar pra View.

Answer (score 8):

Seus modelos (Models no Rails) são abstrações do domínio da sua aplicação. Eles não deveriam ter lógicas de *Crawling*, *Parsing*, coisas do gênero.

Na minha opinião, essa lógica de extrair informações de um link deveria ser realizada por um outro objeto, um *Serviço*.

Tenta dar uma lida sobre *Domain Driven Design*, do Eric Evans. Têm, também, um bom [resumo do infoQ](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly).

Mais na [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)<sup>(en)</sup>.